# require '   ' has suddenly stopped working in ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, json, require

I have been using these files all day... And then suddenly this is now what I get.

```
#!/Users/user969617/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
puts "hello world"
require 'json'
```

output:

```
hello world
rub.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
    from rub.rb:3
```

I can call it from the interactive ruby shell though... super strange.

```
Using /Users/user969617/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
1.9.3p0 :001 > require 'json'
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :002 >
```

Any ideas? I have restarted the computer ;)

------------------ update
I dont use any other require functions, but I just tried require 'Rake' which also returns True in irb, but go the same 'no such file to load'... so it's any require request it seems

Comment: How did you run `rub.rb`? By doing `ruby ruby.rb`, or by doing `./rub.rb`? Also, can you add `puts RUBY_VERSION` to your script?

Comment: Agreed that this is a weird version issue.  Did you have a version of ruby installed before you installed RVM?  I'm guessing this is a Windows install?

Comment: RUBY_VERSION is 1.8.7 according to the script. I run it using ruby rub.rb... if I try to run it using ./ I get "command not found" for all lines. Im on a mac by the way. I have 1.8.7 installed that came with snow leopard, and then 1.9.3 installed using rvm. What really confuses me is why it would suddenly stop working. As it was working with require 'json', and 1.8.7 does not seem to have json installed (well it doesn't work in irb for 1.8.7), the script must have been calling 1.9.3.

Comment: I can confirm that `require 'json'` works on my Ruby 1.9 interpreter, and that it doesn't work on my Ruby 1.8 interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bootstrap RVM in your environment. Run this to add the bootstrapping code to your environment.

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If that doesn't fix it, make sure that you have it installed with your current gemset (RVM supports sets of gems which get added and removed from the environment) `gem list json` If you don't have it, then `gem install json`

Comment: I allready have [[ -s "/Users/ben/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/ben/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
in my .bash_profile, how do i specify that i want to look in 1.9.3 when i call `gem list json` because I know it has it, i can use it in irb when i call `rvm use 1.9.3; irb` the problem seems to be that my computer will not open my scripts in 1.9.3 - but defaults to 1.8.7

Comment: OK I commented out my original code in .bash_profile, restarted terminal and it seems to work again. I am confused as to why it had suddenly stopped working though?